# Proving an identity using Riemann-Stieltjes Integration?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Prove the following identity using Riemann-Stieltjes Integration:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^s} =\frac{1}{N^{s-1}} + s \int_1^N \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x^{s+1}}dx$$

Here's what I have so far:
$$
\begin{align*}
&=\frac{1}{N^{s-1}} + s \int_1^N \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x^{s+1}}dx \\
&= \frac{1}{N^{s-1}} + s\left(\left[\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor x}{x^{s+1}}\right]_1^N - \int_1^N x d(\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x^{s+1}}) \right) \text{by Integration by Parts}\\
&= \frac{1}{N^{s-1}} + s\left( \frac{N^2}{N^{s+1}}-1-\sum_{n=1}^N f(x_n)\alpha_n\right)
\end{align*}
$$
Where $\alpha_n$ is the jump of $\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x^{s+1}}$ at each $x_n$.
Now if we consider a partition $P$ such that $P = \{x_n | x_n = n , n = 1, 2, \ldots , N\}$ we get
$$
\begin{align*}
&=\frac{1}{N^{s-1}} + s\left( \frac{1}{N^{s-1}}-1-\sum_{n=1}^Nn\frac{1}{n^{s+1}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{N^{s-1}} + \frac{s}{N^{s-1}} -s - s\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^s}
\end{align*}
$$

And this is when I get stuck. I couldn't find a mistake in my work above, but what I have now doesn't give me the left hand side of the identity.

Comment: If you want to recapture the Riemann zeta function here you'll have to assume that ${\rm Re}\, s > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

There are two inaccuracies. The first, which is innocuous, is that you have not specified if your integral starts at $(1+)$ or $(1-)$ (so that you catch, or not, a jump at the start), which could have led to a calculation error. The second is the calculation of the differential ${\rm d}(\lceil x\rceil / x^{s+1})$. There should be two parts : one coming from the smooth variations of $1/x^{s+1}$, and the other coming from the jumps. Perhaps you could use the law for the differential of a product ${\rm d}(fg) = f{\rm d}g + ({\rm d}f)g$.